# Issue to share in Facebook with page with iframe of Youtube video

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, video, youtube, share

I'm working on Rails app and I have a webpage with an iframe inside(to show youtube video there). Outside of this iframe I have a Facebook share link. On this page I'm showing a Post. I want to share it into Facebook and I've wrote this link:

```
%a.icon-social.facebook{:href => "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=#{post_url(@post.id)}", :target => "_blank"}
  %i.fa.fa-inverse.fa-facebook
```

But is not showed the correct information. Another tab is opened but it has a wrong information (not corresponding to info of my webpage)

The iframe I have to show the video is:

```
%iframe{:allowfullscreen => "", :frameborder => "0", :height => "365", :src => "//#{youtube_url(@post.link)}?wmode=transparent&amp;rel=0", :width => "644"}
```

I'm not sure if this is the problem. I have a link to share in Google+ on same page and this is working perfect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What information is not showing correctly? Are you expecting the YouTube video to show in the sharer? If so then what you are seeing is correct. Check you og:meta tags on the page and also use the debugger to make sure you have everything set up correctly https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: I wanted to show Post's description, Post's title and a link to Video. Thanks Deep I'll take a look meta tags and og:meta